# Is this a Leaky Bucket Algorithm?

Tags: algorithm

We use this type of filtering algorithm a lot for embedded machine control.  Does anyone know a name for this type of algorithm?  It is somewhat similar to a leaky-bucket algorithm.

Given the periodic occurrence of an event, this 'filtering' algorithm allows a ‘bad’ event to be “undone” by a subsequent ‘good’ event.
If there is an excess of bad events, then the filter triggers.  The filter uses these variables:

- IsBadEvent – TRUE or FALSE status of the current event.
- Threshold – The number of excessive bad events that trigger the filter.
- NumBadEvents – Number of TRUE’s minus the number of FALSE’s.

---

- If IsBadEvent is TRUE, then increment NumBadEvents.                                                         /* Add water to the bucket */
- If IsBadEvent is FALSE, then decrement NumBadEvents (to a floor of 0).                          /* Bucket is leaking water */
- If NumBadEvents exceeds the Threshold, then trigger the filter.                                        /* Bucket overflows. */

Another use of the algorithm is by CAN bus to decide if it should go to ‘bus off’.  In that case, the increments are 8 times the size of decrements.  So it is biased toward failure (i.e., bus off) with still an allowance for ‘self-healing’.

Answer (score 0):

This is not quite a "leaky bucket".  The difference is that a leaky bucket situation has a leak of an effectively constant rate.  If you could guarantee a steady supply of `good` events, *then* you would have a leaky bucket.

Without that, you merely have a heap/queue of finite capacity.  "Leaky bucket" gets a name because the characteristics lend themselves to improved analytic techniques.

Answer (score 0):

This looks quite similar to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUSUM

(CUSUM or cumulative sum control chart)